# How to make a spoiler work in a comment?

Tags: support, spoilers

I am trying guide an answer in a Puzzling Q&A and don't want to give out hints to those who want to keep being challenged. So, how can I make a spoiler in a comment?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on Puzzling Meta?

Comment: Lolz. StackExchange is going to kill me.

Comment: @CinCout that would be my first guess, but apparently not: [avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with Stack Overflow *or the Stack Exchange network*.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Glorfindel, that just says *not* to ask questions that *don't* have to do with the SE network, not to *only* ask questions that *do* have to do with the SE network here. There is a Puzzling Meta, and it should be used for these kinds of questions. Otherwise, why bother having a Puzzling Meta?

Comment: [Hover over this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323913/Maybe_fake_urls_are_the_solution)

Comment: Good idea title but title is stripped it seems

Comment: @hypeJunction Well, don't click on it, just hover over it. There's only so much that can be done in a comment...

Comment: I don't see a tooltip when I hover over

Comment: @hypeJunction In my browser, it shows where the URL leads at the bottom when I hover over it. You can also see it by dragging the link.

Answer (score 10):

> how can I make a spoiler in a comment?

You can't. Spoilers are not supported in comments.

Comments have [limited markdown support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and spoilers are not included.

Comment: Do you agree it would make sense for forums such as Puzzling?

Comment: Nope. If you have a spoiler - use an answer for it. Those support spoilers.

Comment: That makes it practically impossible to comment on the substance of an answer without spoiling the puzzle

Comment: Totally agree that this is a needed feature. Comments are to help improve an answer, not for discussion, so how do you help improve an answer to a puzzle without spoiling it if you can't use spoiler tags?

Answer (score 5):

As @Oded already explained you can't make a spoiler in a comment.

But, what can be helpful is using a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). It's a very simple encryption technique, that allows you to write stuff in comments, that users won't understand before translating them.
One of the examples is [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).

Example:

> The second part could refer to norwegian wood.

I would write in the comment (with the usage of ROT13) this:

> The second part could refer to ROT13(abejrtvna jbbq).

And then whoever wants to know what you wrote, can go to a [website](https://www.rot13.com/), and translate the bit.